# Python from sources: subprocess has no 'run' attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, build, subprocess

I have manually built python3.5.2 from sources on my ubuntu 15.10. The  build process went well, but now when I execute below script

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.run(["ls"]))
```

I receive following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

When I run same script on Windows (where I have installed python3.5.2 via installer) I receive expected output:

```
CompletedProcess(args='ls', returncode=0)
```

On my ubuntu machine subprocess.py is present in and it has "run" function defined.
I anticipated that python3.5.2 could look for subprocess.py in libs folder for 2.7 (preinstalled on ubuntu) but this is not the case.

What could be wrong with my installation?

Comment: Try printing the Python version in your script. `import sys;print sys.version`.

Comment: The traceback message suggests you're still running Python 2, in Python 3(at least in Python 3.5.1) the traceback would have looked like: `AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'run'`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks for your comment. It's really strange because it outputs 3.4.3 on ubuntu and 3.5.2 on windows.

Comment: did you create file `subprocess.py` ? then you import your file instead of expected module.

Comment: @furas no, I didn't create it. I just looked whether it is present on my machine

Comment: it looks like it imports different file with name `subprocess.py` - `import` first looks in local folder and if it finds file `subprocess.py` (or subfolder `subprocess`) then it imports this file instead of expected module.

Comment: you can check `print(subprocess.__file__)` to see full path to imported file.

Comment: BTW: precompiled Python versions 2.3-3.5 for Ubuntu - it can be installed using `apt-get` https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import subprocess
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(subprocess)
```